# How to use Hibernate 4.3 in combination with the JPA 2.1 EntityManager?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, entitymanager

I have been wondering why the Hibernate 4.3 community documentation has no description of using Hibernate 4.3 with the JPA 2.1 Entity Manager.
So, is their any specific reason to don't use the JPA entity manager together with Hibernate 4.3 and my main question is how can I use the JPA EntityManager in combination Hibernate 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

Well, look at the [dependencies of hibernate-entitymanager 4.3](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.5.Final):

> This artifact depends on ...
>
> org.hibernate.javax.persistence   hibernate-jpa-**2.1**-api

So, hibernate EntityManager is an implementation of JPA 2.1. If your project uses the version 4.3.x of Hibernate, it uses JPA 2.1, even if you don't realize it. And you should thus be able to use all the features specified in JPA 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, [JBoss wants you to use EntityManager instead of Session](http://www.theserverside.com/news/2240186700/The-JPA-20-EntityManager-vs-the-Hibernate-Session-Which-one-to-use). The documentation for doing so has moved. You can find it [here](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/4.3/html/Hibernate_EntityManager_User_Guide/).

Also, any book on JPA 2 (such as [Pro JPA 2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430249269)) will be 100% applicable to Hibernate.